# Destructor is called in operator overloading

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, destructor, operator-keyword

Here is my code. The problem is i'm assigning array of class to zero in destructor and when I do operator overloading in my program the destructor is called and my arrays are automatically assigned with 0.

```
    //Overloading Plus Operator
Array Array::operator +(Array &obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        this->arr[i] = this->arr[i] + obj.arr[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

//Overloading Minus Operator
Array Array::operator -(Array obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        this->arr[i] = this->arr[i] - obj.arr[i];
    }

    return *this;
}

//Overloading Assignment Operator
void Array::operator =(Array &obj)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = obj.arr[i];
    }

}


//Class Destructor
Array::~Array()
{
    cout << "\n\nDeleting Object " << this->objNum << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: You are returning a copy of "this".

Comment: @FedeWar so how it can get rid of this problem?

Comment: We need a minimal working example.

Comment: Either return by reference and call the function `operator+=`, or stop working on `this`

Comment: @FedeWar Here is a link to my full code https://anotepad.com/notes/353akc

Comment: @M.M ok let me try by removing this pointer.

Comment: @M.M Correction didn't worked.

Comment: That's not a very useful comment

Answer (score 1):

When you get stuck like this, it's sometimes a big clue that you're doing something wrong.

And you are.

The function you are implementing is `operator+`, whose meaning is generally that `x+y` should leave `x` and `y` unchanged and produce a new object whose value is their sum....

However, your *implementation* is more like that of `x += y`: an operation that changes the value of `x` to be the sum of its original value and `y`.

The problems you are seeing is a symptom of that mismatch.

As an aside, your functions are also const-incorrect — to repair this, for example, declare `operator+` as

```
 Array operator +(const Array &obj) const
```

In fact, if you had additionally declared an `operator[]` that was const correct and accessed the contents of the internal array accessed the contents of the array using this operator, the compiler would have clued you into the fact that you shouldn't be modifying the contents of the array in `operator+`.

Comment: what will be the benefit of using const here?

Comment: @Saad: One benefit is that the compiler enforces the contract that the function shouldn't modify the things marked `const`, which could have clued you into your mistake here. Also other things -- such as actually being able to do `x+y` when `x` is `const`.. "Const correctness" is a thing that you should be doing; you can go look it up.

Comment: thanks for the correction but it isn't working yet. I have used const and also a third object to store x+y but output is same. still destructor is called and array is assigned with 0.